# My flutter project runs on iOS simulator but it doesn't run on a real device and shows a blank screen, why?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, ios-simulator

I'm learning flutter and I did my first project but I cannot run on my iPhone X(it's up to date) also it runs on simulator. When I tried to run it on my device it shows a blank(white) screen.

I couldn't solve this problem and I tried everything I know. I tried "iOS build --release", upgrade flutter, Xcode, VS code and my device, flutter clean and re-build and few more.

By the way I am using MacBook Pro...

Comment: What is logged to the console? Something like: 'Launching *** on *** in debug mode...'?

Comment: when I run on terminal, logged "launch on *my devices name* " but I launch by Xcode

Comment: Before you run your project, try to use 'flutter build ios'

Comment: I tried but it didn't solve my problem. I solved by anything else. thanks...